# Robotic arm moves on loading inside Gazebo

Tags: ros2, robotic-arm, ros-humble, gazebo-11, ros2-control

I am trying to run the `ros2_control_demo_example_7` package of [ros2_control_demos](https://control.ros.org/humble/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_7/doc/userdoc.html) with some modifications to spawn `r6bot` robot inside gazebo. I am not using `gazebo_ros2_control` plugin since on using it I am getting error as pointed out [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/103767/class-gazebo-ros2-control-gazebosystem-with-base-class-type-hardware-interface). As suggested there, I am using `ros2_control_node` in place of `gazebo_ros2_control` plugin.

I have also included the physical properties of each joint in the urdf:

```
<dynamics damping="0.15" friction="0"/>
```

Also, defined the material properties of each link in the gazebo description as below:

```
    <gazebo reference="${prefix}base_link">
        <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
        <mu1 value="0.0"/>
        <mu2 value="0.0"/>
        <kp value="10000000.0"/>
        <kd value="1.0"/>
        <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
    </gazebo>
```

Everything seems to be working in the terminal but I am getting below output in the gazebo:

[image]

**r6bot_controller.launch.py**

```
def generate_launch_description():
    gaz_pkg_share = FindPackageShare(package='ros2_control_demo_example_7').find('ros2_control_demo_example_7')

    world_file_name = 'empty.world'
    world_path = os.path.join(gaz_pkg_share, 'worlds', world_file_name)

    # Set the path to the SDF model files.
    gazebo_models_path = os.path.join(gaz_pkg_share, 'models')
    
    if 'GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH' in os.environ:
        os.environ['GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH'] =  os.environ['GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH'] + ':' + gazebo_models_path
    else:
        os.environ['GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH'] =  gazebo_models_path

    # Get URDF via xacro
    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [
                    FindPackageShare("ros2_control_demo_example_7"),
                    "urdf",
                    "r6bot.urdf.xacro",
                ]
            ),
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}

    robot_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare("ros2_control_demo_example_7"),
            "config",
            "r6bot_controller.yaml",
        ]
    )
    rviz_config_file = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare("ros2_control_demo_description"), "r6bot/rviz", "view_robot.rviz"]
    )

    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            [PathJoinSubstitution([FindPackageShare("gazebo_ros"), "launch", "gazebo.launch.py"])]
        ),
        launch_arguments={"verbose": "true",
                          "paused":"false",
                          "gui":"true",
                          "world":world_path,
                          "headless":"false",
                          "use_sim_time":"true"}.items(),
    )

    spawn_entity = Node(
        package="gazebo_ros",
        executable="spawn_entity.py",
        arguments=["-topic", "robot_description", "-entity", "r6bot"],
        output="screen",
    )

    control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[robot_description, robot_controllers],
        remappings=[
            (
                "/forward_position_controller/commands",
                "/position_commands",
            ),
        ],
        output="both",
    )
    
    joint_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package="joint_state_publisher_gui",
        executable="joint_state_publisher_gui",
        condition=IfCondition("true"),
    )

    robot_state_pub_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        output="both",
        parameters=[robot_description],
    )
    rviz_node = Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="log",
        arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file],
    )

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    robot_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["r6bot_controller", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    # Delay rviz start after `joint_state_broadcaster`
    delay_rviz_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            on_exit=[rviz_node],
        )
    )

    # Delay start of robot_controller after `joint_state_broadcaster`
    delay_robot_controller_spawner_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            on_exit=[robot_controller_spawner],
        )
    )

    nodes = [
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        control_node,
        robot_state_pub_node,
        gazebo,
        spawn_entity,
        joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        delay_rviz_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        delay_robot_controller_spawner_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
    ]

    return LaunchDescription(nodes)
```

**r6bot_controller.yaml**

```
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10  # Hz

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    r6bot_controller:
      type: ros2_control_demo_example_7/RobotController

    forward_position_controller:
      type: forward_command_controller/ForwardCommandController


forward_position_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - joint_1
      - joint_2
      - joint_3
      - joint_4
      - joint_5
      - joint_6

    interface_name: position

r6bot_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - joint_1
      - joint_2
      - joint_3
      - joint_4
      - joint_5
      - joint_6

    command_interfaces:
      - position

    state_interfaces:
      - position
```

**ros2 control**

(Here I am using `ros2_control_demo_example_8/RRBotTransmissionsSystemPositionOnlyHardware` plugin, defined in the [ros2_control_demo_example_8](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/humble/example_8/hardware/rrbot_transmissions_system_position_only.cpp) package)

```
<ros2_control name="${name}" type="system">

  <hardware>
    <plugin>ros2_control_demo_example_8/RRBotTransmissionsSystemPositionOnlyHardware</plugin>
    <param name="actuator_slowdown">100.0</param>
  </hardware>
  
  <joint name="joint_1">
    <command_interface name="position">
      <param name="min">{-2*pi}</param>
      <param name="max">{2*pi}</param>
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint_2">
    <command_interface name="position">
      <param name="min">{-2*pi}</param>
      <param name="max">{2*pi}</param>
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint_3">
    <command_interface name="position">
      <param name="min">{-pi}</param>
      <param name="max">{pi}</param>
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint_4">
    <command_interface name="position">
      <param name="min">{-2*pi}</param>
      <param name="max">{2*pi}</param>
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint_5">
    <command_interface name="position">
      <param name="min">{-2*pi}</param>
      <param name="max">{2*pi}</param>
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint_6">
    <command_interface name="position">
      <param name="min">{-2*pi}</param>
      <param name="max">{2*pi}</param>
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
  </joint>

  <transmission name="transmission1">
    <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
    <actuator name="actuator1" role="actuator1"/>
    <joint name="joint_1" role="joint_1">
      <mechanical_reduction>4.0</mechanical_reduction>
      <offset>0.0</offset>
    </joint>
  </transmission>

  <transmission name="transmission2">
    <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
    <actuator name="actuator2" role="actuator2"/>
    <joint name="joint_2" role="joint_2">
      <mechanical_reduction>4.0</mechanical_reduction>
      <offset>0.0</offset>
    </joint>
  </transmission>

  <transmission name="transmission3">
    <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
    <actuator name="actuator3" role="actuator3"/>
    <joint name="joint_3" role="joint_3">
      <mechanical_reduction>4.0</mechanical_reduction>
      <offset>0.0</offset>
    </joint>
  </transmission>

  <transmission name="transmission4">
    <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
    <actuator name="actuator4" role="actuator4"/>
    <joint name="joint_4" role="joint_4">
      <mechanical_reduction>4.0</mechanical_reduction>
      <offset>0.0</offset>
    </joint>
  </transmission>

  <transmission name="transmission5">
    <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
    <actuator name="actuator5" role="actuator5"/>
    <joint name="joint_5" role="joint_5">
      <mechanical_reduction>4.0</mechanical_reduction>
      <offset>0.0</offset>
    </joint>
  </transmission>

  <transmission name="transmission6">
    <plugin>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</plugin>
    <actuator name="actuator6" role="actuator6"/>
    <joint name="joint_6" role="joint_6">
      <mechanical_reduction>4.0</mechanical_reduction>
      <offset>0.0</offset>
    </joint>
  </transmission>

</ros2_control>
```

I am expecting robotic arm to spawn inside gazebo with below configuration:
[image]

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Is this happening because of PID or other parameters? I would really appreciate some advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `gazebo_ros2_control` plugin as

```
<gazebo>
   <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
      <parameters>$(find ros2_control_demo_example_7)/config/r6bot_controller.yaml</parameters>
   </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

Remove the `control_node` from `r6bot_controller.launch.py`.

Also, Include `gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem` hardware plugin as

```
<plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to use gazebo if you take the hardware component from example_8? How do you interface gazebo at all if you use the hardware component?

Use gazebo_ros2_control, because this loads the controller_manager and all your controller plugins. There is no need for ros2_control_node then.

Comment: You are right that either hardware component from example_8 or `gazebo_ros2_control` should be used. Not both. Initially, `gazebo_ros2_control` plugin wasn't working. Was getting errors like no `controller_manager` available. Now everything is fixed. Thanks1